# Why won't my div background color change?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrrrf.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVLVR.jpg)

When I change the background color of the entire page it's working but when I change the specific div container background color it's not working

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please post your code, and not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the backgtround color doesn't change is because you don't have any content in your `<div>`. If you add some `html` to your `<div>`, you will see the background color that you set in your `css`.